Issue with the netmeta function
I am trying to do a network meta-analysis, but while using the netmeta function, R mixes my treatment and control conditions.
In my treat1 condition I have the following categories (treatment) : Ketamine, MDMA, TM, MANTRAM, MBSR, MI, MORE
In my treat2 condition the following (control): ACTI, INAC, TAU, WL
I also have a " vs " column, that gives the order of comparison for each study, e.g. "Treat1 vs Treat2"
But when I run the netmeta function :
> m.netmeta <- netmeta(TE = yi,
+                      seTE = vi,
+                      treat1 = Type1,
+                      treat2 = Type2,
+                      studlab = study_year,
+                      data = New_database,
+                      sm = "SMD",
+                      fixed = FALSE,
+                      random = TRUE,
+                      reference.group = "TAU",
+                      details.chkmultiarm = TRUE,
+                      sep.trts = " vs ")


R switches the order for some, but not all studies. Specifically, all studies with a treat2 condition corresponding to ACTI or INAC are in the opposite order from the rest of the studies.
Here is an example, with the beginning of the output R :
Original data:

                        treat1   treat2      TE   seTE
Abdallah et al._2022      INAC KETAMINE  0.1341 0.0461
Bormann et al._2013    MANTRAM      TAU -0.2632 0.0277
Dumarkaite et al._2021      TM       WL -0.8594 0.0632
Feder et al._2021         ACTI KETAMINE  0.7908 0.1438
Gallegos et al._2020      ACTI     MBSR  0.3591 0.2580
Garland et al._2016       MORE      TAU -3.7434 0.0953
Kearney et al._2013       MBSR      TAU -0.4913 0.0880
Mitchell et al._2023      INAC     MDMA  0.5915 0.0449
Mithoefer et al._2018     ACTI     MDMA  0.9602 0.2505
Mithoefer et al._2011     INAC     MDMA  3.8296 0.5750
Nidich et al._2018        ACTI       TM  0.3549 0.0303
Niles et al._2012         ACTI     MBSR  1.2346 0.1766
Oehen et al._2013         ACTI     MDMA  0.8522 0.4053
Ot’alora et al._2018      ACTI     MDMA  0.2755 0.2456
Possemato et al._2016     ACTI       MI  0.0495 0.0663
Rees et al._2013            TM       WL -6.7296 0.6344
Wahbeh et al._2016        ACTI       MI  0.0891 0.0771
Zhao et al._2023            MI       WL -0.5161 0.0290


The treat1 and treat 2 columns are now mixed and treat1 has both control and treatment conditions, and the same is true for treat2.
One hypothesis is that R puts the two columns always in alphabetical order, but I don't know why, or how to fix it
